# Error on getting data from twitter

Tags: python, twitter

```
import twitter
api=twitter.Api()
page=1
count=0
while(page<=2):
    tweets=api.GetSearch("#ghaza",per_page=200)
    twitterapi.until:2011-05-09
    for k in tweets:
        print k.text

    page+=1
```

I run the code, code run correctly when I didn't enter the `twitterapi.until:2011-05-09` but I want data about specific date's but It give scientific error on it. I notice the above code syntax on https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation, you'll find `until` is to be used within the search query.

Here your usage to `until:` violates Python Syntax as the colon is used in
function & class definition, conditionals and loops. And also `twitterapi.until` will be undefined.

So, I believe you should change `tweets=api.GetSearch("#ghaza",per_page=200)` to `tweets=api.GetSearch("#ghaza until:2011-05-09",per_page=200)`. That if the select query in the api is `"#ghaza"`.